# How to delay execution of code in a Meteor Package until another optional Package has been loaded

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor Package `A` that has a weak dependency on package `B`, such that certain feature sets are only made available if `B` is being used by the app itself.

I have code that needs to be executed **after** `B` is loaded, but before Meteor.startup() is called.

I've tried changing the package order in .meteor/packages but that didn't solve my issue.

Can anyone conceive of some hackery to achieve this? I'm wondering if there's a way of creating a temporary `B` object that calls back my code once the true `B`is created by the package.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_use):

> Establish a weak dependency on a package. If package A has a weak
>   dependency on package B, it means that including A in an app does not
>   force B to be included too — but, if B is included or by another
>   package, then B will load before A. You can use this to make packages
>   that optionally integrate with or enhance other packages if those
>   packages are present. When you weakly depend on a package you don't
>   see its exports. You can detect if the possibly-present
>   weakly-depended-on package is there by seeing if Package.foo exists,
>   and get its exports from the same place.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it already seems to be doing what you want. Perhaps the key point is that you don't automatically see its exports and need to check `Package.foo` to see if it exists.

For example if I'm using the `aldeed:autoform` package I can access it with `Package['aldeed:autoform'].AutoForm`

If it's not working as intended, it may be a bug rather than a missing feature.

Comment: Hmm, you're quite right. However, I have a weak dependency on the React package, yet at the point that I try to call React.createClass from my code I'm informed that React isn't defined.

Comment: Try to access with `Package['reactjs:react'].react`

Comment: hmm, I added `reactjs:react` to my app using `meteor add`. Running `Package['reactjs:react']` returns an object with both `React` and `ReactMeteor`...